# Can I ask a same question in another SE site and here in Stack Overlow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, cross-posting

Can I ask same question in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and in another site (Example: [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)) simultaneously?

Answer (score 4):

You *can*, technically.

You **should not**, however.

Ask the question where it is most appropriate in your eyes. If needed, it can get migrated.

Asking on two (or more) sites on the network makes migration much more difficult.

Comment: And as a rule we will delete the newer version of that question on whatever site it got posted on.

Comment: as a user, i expect more ppl to see that question and give better answer. Then why sholdn't i post in two?

Comment: @Karthiprime - In the Stack Exchange network, we would like to have a single authoritative answer for any one question. Posting the question is two places (or more) means there is less chance of future users finding that authoritative answer.

Comment: We would rather have one great question and answer than 2 or 3 mediocre ones.

Comment: @JNK, how does the "delete the newer version" works? How we proceed when find a Multi-post? I've never seen a topic here on Meta about this...

Comment: @brasofilo - There is no such feature. It is entirely by users finding such dupes and flagging them as cross-posts.

Comment: So, we should flag the newest one and use "Other" with the address of the other one?

Comment: @brasofilo - Either way. So long as the mods are aware. Try to look at site suitability, so the "Other" is the suitable one.

Comment: Got it, gracias!

Comment: @brasofilo - de nada.

Answer (score 1):

If you do, bear in mind that you're asking two different audiences, with two different focusses, and should be expecting different answers. There should be a *reason* for asking on both sites, and you should phrase your question to make that reason apparent. If you write the question completely differently, with a different focus, for each site, that should be fine.

(In other words, *don't* ask the *same* question on both sites, but you can ask two *different* but *overlapping* questions on both sites.)

Comment: U have wonderful reason. I understood. But as a user, i expect more ppl to see that question and give better answer. Then why sholdn't i post in two? You ppl have any administrative problems?

Comment: Because that's the way we roll here. [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) and [SO] are not completely independent communities: many people participate in both. So asking identical questions in both places is spamming. Also, please learn to type: capital letters and proper spelling is important: This should be a canonical question, which will be useful to others, not a text message.